# Flask : Why does not the HTML submit button redirect the page to the target URL?

Tags: python, html, http, flask, http-post

I'm new to Flask. This is the content of my `login.html` file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="localhost:5000/login" method="POST">
            <p>Enter name : </p>
            <p><input type = "text" name="nm"/></p>
            <p><input type = "submit" value="submit"/></p>
        </form>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

This is `app.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request  
app = Flask(__name__)  
     
@app.route('/success/<name>')  
def success(name):  
    return "Welcome %s" % name

@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        user = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('success', name = user))

    else :
        user = request.args.get('nm')
        return redirect(url_for('success', name = user))    
      
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

When I entered a text in my `HTML` login form and click the `submit` it should have redirected to the desired URL but nothing happened.

**Edit**

After trying with changes suggested by Rogan Josh, i got this error:

```
File not found

Firefox can’t find the file at /home/hp/flask_practice/{{ url_for('login') }}.

    Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

Comment: Just put <form action="login" method="POST">

Comment: Does the server logfile show a POST request being made to the expected url?

Comment: @VyshakPuthusseri : after clicking submit, i got 'file not found'

Comment: What file was not found? It shouldn't be that anyway, it should be `<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">`

Comment: The code doesn't make sense, your app isn't running so you have no server

Comment: "file not found" is an odd response from a web server.  Did you actually mean "404 Not Found"?

Comment: @roganjosh : check my edit portion

Comment: @JohnGordon : check my edit portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can't do anything because you haven't actually served the html from your flask application. You've just double-clicked it and opened the HTML in a browser.

Your html file needs to go in a subdirectory from `app.py` called "templates". Then change your code to:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template  
app = Flask(__name__)  
     
@app.route('/success/<name>')  
def success(name):  
    return "Welcome %s" % name

@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        user = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('success', name = user))

    else :
        user = request.args.get('nm') # THIS DOES NOTHING
        return render_template('login.html')  # CHANGED HERE  
      
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

You should also update your HTML to:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="POST">
            <p>Enter name : </p>
            <p><input type = "text" name="nm"/></p>
            <p><input type = "submit" value="submit"/></p>
        </form>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

Now open the browser and go to `127.0.0.1:5000/login`

Comment: it worked. Thank you. I'm absolutely beginner and was following this tutorial -  https://www.javatpoint.com/flask-http-methods

It seems I should stop following this. Should I?

Comment: @Debbie the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) is one of the best I have seen, not just for Flask, but across all Python tutorials